# Is Pandas better for my Jinja2 template than pure python?

Tags: python, pandas, jinja2

I'm working on an html email that will provide the on-call coverage for a number of different groups.

**Overview**

1. Read API data that represents on-call coverage by team
2. Manipulate the json into a pandas dataframe by group, primary/
   secondary on-call for each day of the week

   - the report displays data from Monday to Monday currently (hard-coded
     for 9/24/18 through 10/1/18 for demonstration purposes)
   - shifts with replacements will need to show that information for any day(s) that they will be providing coverage for along with the start time
   - the rotation time should similarly show the time that the primary/ secondary, etc...will be taking over from a coverage standpoint
3. Pass it to a Jinja2 template for output

**Question:**  Is pandas the right tool for the job here?  I was hoping to avoid any logic within Jinja2 but don't yet know the best approach to accomplish that with Pandas or otherwise.

Here's a link to a jupyter notebook with example output along with the raw api data.  The code is functional but probably will need to be overhauled.  I'm hoping the feedback I get here can point me in the right direction though.  ...still a novice with python and pandas so thanks in advance!

> > https://github.com/RobinsonCW/servicecenter/blob/master/scripts/python/jupyter/xmatters/oncall_report_analysis/notebooks/oncall_report_analysis.ipynb

[Example Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz4dF.png)

Comment: With the greatest respect, you seem to be considering them as competing tools. They're not. Pandas _should_ be faster for proper data crunching if it is called for, but that doesn't mean you wouldn't also want to put at least some logic in jinja in order to get something rendered as you wanted. The pure-python method doesn't seem to have been mentioned in your question.

Comment: I would think so, yes. Even though your notebook won't load for me for some reason, the type of problem you're dealing with sounds like something I would use pandas for. Pandas works well with both tabular data, and datetime (e.g. querying a certain date or week).

Comment: Sorry, the prior version of this report was pure python.  I haven’t gotten the new pandas version to run any faster but I think that’s more due to how I’m currently “munging” the data.  If I run the report with 20-30 teams it can run in under 20 seconds or so, which is about the same as the all python version.  But I was hoping to get it down to sub 5 seconds.  If anyone has suggestions on the steps I’m using to get it to the desired output that would be greatly appreciated though.

Comment: I see what you mean about the notebook not loading.  It’s not rendering the html on github so let me remove that so that at least people can see the code and steps to get to the end result.